# Unable to login as root or as user because zsh is missing

Tags: linux, shell, raspberry-pi, debian, zsh

I installed zsh on my raspberry pi and for various reasons including the fact that the shell completely slowed down, I decided to remove it. I uninstall the package, changed the shell back to /bin/bash and assumed all would be ok. However, It looks like there was an issue uninstalling it.

When I tried to log back into the pi, via SSH, I was shown the following:

```
Welcome to KRATOS
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I know that the public key was fine as it's worked in the past, so I hooked the pi up to a monitor to see the log as it awoke. It ran everything as expected, and then when I attempted to login with the username and password of `pi`, it logged me in, then presented the error and proceeded to log me out.

```
Cannot execute /usr/bin/zsh: No such file or directory
```

The same happens when I try to login as `root`.

Have I completely locked myself out of the system, or is there a way of getting back in? Worst comes to worst, I can try and mount the filesystem onto another laptop and change the configuration from there?

Comment: Can you try specifying bash as the shell with the ssh command ? `ssh -t root@host bash`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess that the default shell for root user is `/usr/bin/zsh`
This is configured in `/etc/passwd`
Do you have another account on that system with another default shell? If so, if you have configured sudo perhaps it's possible to edit the `/etc/passwd` file with sudo and change the default shell to `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash`.

Otherwise you have to mount the filesystem/disk from a bootable usb-stick or do a network boot, or mount it from another device and fix it that way.

Comment: Fantastic, I did have another user on the system - by chance!

Answer (score -1):

If you first do sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade (this will give you temporary permissions as root, even with the previous error)

then do sudo nano /etc/passwd  and change the default for root from /usr/bin/zsh to /bin/sh or /bin/bash and it will work. (just solved doing that. Thank you Mark van Herpen for help)

Comment: What does `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` have to do with this question?  How is the user supposed to issue this command line when he can't get to a shell prompt? How does your answer "give [the user] temporary permissions as root"?